# Using Ansible to move subdirectories and files in a given path to a parent

Tags: shell, ansible, mv

I need to move files from `/var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5` to `/var/www/html/internal`

I am using the below script to perform the move.  I also trtied it with `command` in stead of `shell`

The below script moves the files from under the 5.5 directory to `/var/www/html/internal/5.5`.  I need them to be under `/var/www/html/internal`

```
- name: Move confluent packages to /var/www/html/internal
  command: mv /var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5 /var/www/html/internal/
  when: internal_stat.stat.exists
```

How should I formulate the command to make sure the files and subdirectories are moved under `/var/www/html/internal` and not `/var/www/html/internal/5.5` ?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing ansible-specific about this question. How would you accomplish this task in the shell by hand if you weren't using ansible?

Comment: I was doing `mv /var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5/*.* /var/www/html/internal/` that was not copying the subdirectories only files.  It seems I have to do `mv /var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5/* /var/www/html/internal/`  Initially I had thought that wouldn't copy the files, only directories, but this seems too work for both files and directories.  Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing

`mv /var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5/*.* /var/www/html/internal/`

that was not copying the subdirectories only files. It seems I have to do

`mv /var/www/html/internal/packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.5/* /var/www/html/internal/`.

Initially I had thought that wouldn't copy the files, only directories, but this seems to work for both files and directories.  This does not move the .  files, I will research that later